# Dependence of Riemann curvature on the connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The connection depends on the way we define the parallel transport the basis vector $\{e_\mu\}$: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\triangledown_\nu e_\mu=\Gamma_{\nu\mu}^\lambda e_\lambda. 
\end{eqnarray}
It is known that we have the degree of freedom to get another connection by a different parallel transport rule
\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde{\Gamma}_{\nu\mu}^\lambda={\Gamma}_{\nu\mu}^\lambda+t_{\nu\mu}^\lambda
\end{eqnarray}
where $t_{\nu\mu}^\lambda$ is a tensor.

However, the Riemann curvature
\begin{eqnarray}
R^\kappa_{\lambda\mu\nu}(\Gamma)=\partial_\mu\Gamma^\kappa_{\nu\lambda}-\partial_\nu\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\lambda}+\Gamma^\eta_{\nu\lambda}\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\eta}-\Gamma^\eta_{\mu\lambda}\Gamma^\kappa_{\nu\eta}
\end{eqnarray}
is not invariant under the above redefinition of parallel transport, or
\begin{eqnarray}
R^\kappa_{\lambda\mu\nu}(\tilde{\Gamma})\neq R^\kappa_{\lambda\mu\nu}(\Gamma). 
\end{eqnarray}
My question is how to understand such non-invariance. If Riemann curvature indeed depends on the underlying parallel transport rule, does it mean that Riemann curvature is not so intrinsic a quantity? The same question can be asked on the torsion tensor as well.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your understanding of an intrinsic quantity? if you change the rule for parallel transport you are changing the local geometry, so it should not come as a surprise that the curvature changes, as well. In general you cannot just change the connection that way. If you have a Riemannian metric on a manifold $M$ then there is a _unique_ connection which is compatible with the metric. In other words, changes to parallel transport are only possible by changing the metric, hence lengths and angles (and in consequence, of course, curvature).

Comment: @Thomas when we say "local geometry" are we referring to the metric or the connection? As far as I understand these do not have to be related in general.

Comment: @Jeaj My (possibly somewhat biased personal) view on the term local geometry is typically associated with a metric (since this induces distances and angles and so on). This is, however, not really relevant for this question since there no need for a metric if you want to define parallel transport. And of course you can then consider this as a (maybe incomplete) description of a local geometry. In both cases it should not come as a surprise that the curvature changes when you change this data (which is intrinsic, as long as you can define it without referring to some ambient space or similar).

Comment: @Thomas thanks for answering, I was considering the possibility that the "bending of the surface"(curvature) was considered something locally geometric(this is how I interpret what you wrote in the first comment), which only depends on the connection(unless it is Levi-Cevita). I have a few follows questions if you dont mind. Firstly, what is "this" in "And of course you can then consider this as a (maybe incomplete) description of a local geometry"

Comment: @Jeaj 'This' in that sentence is the definition of parallel transport or, equivalently, the connection. And actually yes, I do mind follow up questions -- extended discussions are deprecated at this site. If you have follow up questions just post them as a normal question.